# Asymptotic expansion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I wanted to expand a function of $x$ about $x=\infty$ and see its coefficients as a function of the parameters $m,n,q,y$ and I wrote this - but it didn't work!

It gave me back a very complicated expression with powers of $x$ scattered everywhere - but I want a Laurent series expansion of it!

Can someone kindly help with this?

```
Assuming [ y ∈ Reals &&  m ∈ Reals && q > 0 &&  n ∈ Integers    && x > 0 , Series [   ((  
  Gamma [ I x + (1 + y)/2]   Gamma [ -I x + (1 + y)/2]    )/( 
  Gamma [I  x] Gamma [ -I  x] ) )* (1/( 
  x^2  + m^2 + (n/q)^2)), {x, Infinity, 3}] ]
```

To write it readably - the function is, 
$\frac{ \Gamma (ix + (1+y)/2) \Gamma( -ix + (1+y)/2)}{\Gamma (- i x) \Gamma (i x) } \frac{1}{x^2 + m^2 + (n/q)^2 }$

---

On some computers and Mathematica versions - the answer to the above comes out as -

```
(1/x)^-y (1/x+(2 π (-m^2/(2 π)-n^2/(2 π q^2))+1/24 (-y +y^3)) (1/x)^3+O[1/x]^4)
```

but I don't know why on my computer and Mathematica it doesn'!

---

Some simple examples do work like Series [ x/(x^2 + 3) , {x, Infinity, 2}]

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the real part of the argument in the `Gamma` functions is not recognized as being real. The only thing you have to do in order to circumvent this problem is to give a name to the quantity that appears as the real part and specify explicitly that **it** is real. Here I do this:

```
Simplify[
 Assuming[
   y ∈ Reals && m ∈ Reals && q > 0 && n ∈ Integers && x > 0, 
   Series[((Gamma[I x + y] Gamma[-I x + y])/(Gamma[I x] Gamma[-I x])
          )*(1/(x^2 + m^2 + (n/q)^2)), 
      {x, Infinity, 4}]] /. y -> (1 + y)/2
 ]
```

[image: output]

The variable `y` is initially used only to denote the troublesome real part, and then at the end of the calculation I replace it by what you really want the real part to look like, using the replacement rule `y -> (1 + y)/2`.

Note that I also went one step higher in the expansion order to get the parameters to appear in the result, as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any general lesson here that I can takeway?

Comment: Like I am now stuck with this - 
    Assuming [ M > 0 && x > 0 && a > 0 , 
 Series [ M^2 Exp [2 I x] Tanh [\[Pi] M Exp [I x] ]  Log [ 
    M^2 Exp[2 i x] + a^2], {M, Infinity, 2}]] 
(
SeriesData[M, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
   E^(Complex[0, 2] x) (Log[E^(2 i x)] - 2 Log[M^(-1)]), 0, 
    a^2 E^(Complex[0, 2] x - 2 i x), 0, 
    Rational[-1, 2] a^4 E^(Complex[0, 2] x - 4 i x)}, -2, 3, 1]) Tanh[
  E^(I x) M \[Pi]]

Comment: Here as earlier again the "Tanh" function doesn't get expanded - why?

Comment: More readably I want to expand asymptotically in $M$ for some given $x , a >0$ the function, $M^2 e^{2ix} Tanh[\pi M e^{ix}] Log[M^2 e^{2ix} + a^2]$

Comment: That case is again very different. You're asking for an asymptotic expansion of `Tanh` in its argument, which [doesn't exist](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/57746). I'm afraid there isn't anything more general I can say, there are too many possibilities. Maybe the best advice is to boil your expression down as far as you  can by eliminating unnecessary variables that can be absorbed or scaled out.

Comment: I mean - Tanh[x] goes to 1 as x goes to Infinity - then shouldn't Mathematica have substituted a 1?

Comment: You can get that to work if you use a different expansion variable, e.g.: `Series[Tanh[Log[z]], {z, Infinity, 2}]` but not with the variable `M`, as explained in the link I posted. But that's basically a math question, and *Mathematica* is handling it correctly, I believe.